# Changing UIImageView with button

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimageview

I am wanting to press a button and alternate between two images with one UIImageView.

Right now when I run it, I press the button, the image changes but will not change back. What do I need to change in this action code to make it alternate?

```
- (IBAction)Change:(id)sender {
   image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"car.png"];

}
```

Comment: You mean that if you tap button once you need one Image and when you tap it second time you need a different one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following code :

```
- (IBAction)Change:(id)sender {

        if ([sender isSelected]) 
        {  
          imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"car.png"];
          [sender setSelected:NO];  
        }
        else 
        {     
          imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bike.png"];
          [sender setSelected:YES]; 
        }
}
```

---

To Display sequence image on button click.

`.h` file :

```
int counter;
```

`.m` file :

in `viewDidLoad` initialize `counter = 0`

Then

```
- (IBAction)Change:(id)sender {  
     counter++;
     imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",counter]];
}
```

And give your image name like `1.png`, `2.png`, `3.png` and so on...

Comment: That worked really well and was short, clean code. If I were to add a third image to this, how would that code look?

Comment: @sdlabs : First decide how many images you want to display? Is that in sequence order or random order ?

Comment: I guess sequence order will be good to start with for this exercise.

Comment: Then you have to maintain counter and on button click increase it by one and load image from array.

Answer (score 1):

You have to maintain a flag.

In Somewhere before tapping the button, assign the flag

```
  BOOL isFirstImageShown=YES;
```

Then on your button action

```
- (IBAction)Change:(id)sender {
   if(isFirstImageShown)
   {
      isFirstImageShown=NO;
      yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourSecondImage.png"];
   }
   else
   {
     isFirstImageShown=YES;
     yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourFirstImage.png"];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want that on button click you need another image  you have to first set the image when you load the view and then on button click.